# Split up the total of a value when merging dataframes with rows that contain id multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that I would like to merge. The first dataframe contains a customer id and a column with a value. The second dataframe contains the customer id and a purchase id. When merging i would like to split up the total value in the first dataframe based on how many times the customer id is present in the second dataframe and attribute every row the correct split of the total value.

Example: Customer with id 1 has a total value of 3000 but has bought products two times in its lifetime the value 3000 should then be split when merging so that each row gets 1500.

First dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df_first = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'value': [3000,4000,5000,6000,7000]})

df_first.head()

    Out[1]: 
customer_id value
0   1   3000
1   2   4000
2   3   5000
3   4   6000
4   5   7000
```

Second dataframe:

```
df_second = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5], 'purchase_id': [11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25]})

df_second.head(10)


    Out[2]:
customer_id purchase_id
0   1   11
1   2   12
2   3   13
3   4   14
4   5   15
5   1   21
6   2   22
7   3   23
8   4   24
9   5   25
```

Expected output when merging:

```
    Out[3]:
customer_id value   purchase_id
0   1   1500    11
1   1   1500    21
2   2   2000    12
3   2   2000    22
4   3   2500    13
5   3   2500    23
6   4   3000    14
7   4   3000    24
8   5   3500    15
9   5   3500    25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and sorted values by `customer_id` and then divide values by length of groups mapped by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) :

```
df = df_second.sort_values('customer_id').merge(df_first, on='customer_id', how='left')
df['value'] /= df['customer_id'].map(df['customer_id'].value_counts())
#alternative
#df['value'] /= df.groupby('customer_id')['customer_id'].transform('size')
print (df)
   customer_id  purchase_id   value
0            1           11  1500.0
1            1           21  1500.0
2            2           12  2000.0
3            2           22  2000.0
4            3           13  2500.0
5            3           23  2500.0
6            4           14  3000.0
7            4           24  3000.0
8            5           15  3500.0
9            5           25  3500.0
```